# How to use NOT contains in freemarker Apache?

Tags: apache, freemarker, contains

I want to check if my URL does not contains certain word and depends on this criteria want to change meta url tag. Here is what I do

```
<#if theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word")>
    <#else>
    <meta property="og:url" content=........... />
    </#if>
```

But it seems not very cool, any one know if there is an opposite of contains in freemarker? Something like  ?notcontains("word")

Comment: Could you explain what's the problem with this? what if you using `theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word") == false` expression as far as I see `!theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word")` should be negated?

Comment: yes i was looking for this theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word") == false . Thanks

Comment: I sent as an answer, so you can accept it if it works and close this question

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two options

```
<#if theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word") == false>
<meta property="og:url" content=........... />
</#if>
```

or

```
<#if !theme_display.getURLCurrent()?contains("word")>
<meta property="og:url" content=........... />
</#if>
```